# how to create a object form a function without using a new keyword

Tags: javascript

i have a function. say function createObj() {  }

1. var obj1= new createObj();
2. var obj2= createObj();

what changes you need to make in the function createObj() to support both above secenario with and without new keyword. Both should work at the same time.

Comment: `var newObj = {}`..? And check for `this` inside the function to differentiate.

Comment: will not it break when you use the new createObj()?

Comment: Check Object.create() and instanceOf operator

Answer (score 1):

In the function test the type of `this` and use the new keyword internally, whenever required

```
function createObj()
{
   if ( !(this instanceof createObj) )
      return new createObj();

   // add existing code of function createObj here ...
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

I can advice to you to read some books about JavaScript. [Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)

And you can use this small example:

```
function Sample() { // Sample is the constructor function for your objects

    return {

        prop_1: 'value',
        prop_2: 3
    }
}

var obj = Sample(); // without new

console.log(obj); // Object { prop_1="value",  prop_2=3}

var obj = new Sample(); // with new

console.log(obj); // The same result with new operator: Object { prop_1="value",  prop_2=3}
```

> This is possible only if the return value of your constructor is an object

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky and I don't really recommend doing this but I understand the reasons for why it's sometimes necessary if you need to integrate with some legacy code or transition your API. Here's one way of doing it.

First, we need a way to detect if our function is called with `new` or not. Now, depending on weather we're in strict mode or not, if it's not called with `new` then `this` will either be `undefined` or the global object. If it's called with `new` then it will be an instance of the object inherited from the prototype. So here's how we can check:

```
function createObj () {
    if (typeof this == 'undefined' || typeof this.Array == 'function') {
        // Not called with `new`
    }
    else {
        // Called with `new`
    }
}
```

Now using this we can properly construct the object:

```
function createObj () {
    var self; // replacement of `this` because what it points to
              // depends on the logic below:

    if (typeof this == 'undefined' || typeof this.Array == 'function') {
        // Not called with `new`
        self = Object.create(createObj.prototype); // create object instance
    }
    else {
        // Called with `new`
        self = this;
    }

    // From this point on do things normally except use `self`
    // instead of `this`..


    // Remember to return `self` at the end for when we are not
    // called with `new`:
    return self;
}
```

Now the function can be used as either a constructor or object factory.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the previous answer cause there is a simpler way

---

Actually there is a simpler way to do that

```
function o(n, s) {

  function inner(n, s){
    this.name = n;
    this.surname = s;
  }

  return new inner(n, s);
}

var lee1 = new o('Bruce', 'Lee'),
    lee2 = o('Brandon', 'Lee');
console.log(lee1);
console.log(lee2);
```

Comment: btw if You need such a function ... there must be really bigger and much scary problems in Your code

Comment: This function returns a string "BruceLee" (and not an object) when used without the `new` keyword